# iMagick Distort in perspective on windows server

Tags: php, windows, imagick

I'm trying to distort an image in perspective via imagick php extension and I've got the following piece of code for doing this:

```
    $controlPoints = array(
                    0,0, 0,0, 
                    0,$height, 0,$height, 
                    $width,0, $width,$perspective_wrap, 
                    $width,$height, $width,$hps
                    );
$im1->setImageMatte(true);
//Distort the image -- In perspective with the matrix given above
$im1->distortImage(Imagick::DISTORTION_PERSPECTIVE, $controlPoints, true);
```

The image is distorting in perspective on a linux server but when I move the script on windows hosting it seems that the following error occurs: 
**Fatal error**:  Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'Can't read argument array'

Where the line is **$im1->distortImage(Imagick::DISTORTION_PERSPECTIVE, $controlPoints, true);**

Is there any way to make it work on both platforms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that on my linux server I had the following Imagick Version:
ImageMagick version:    ImageMagick 6.7.6-8 2012-05-02 Q16 
and on the windows server: 
ImageMagick version     ImageMagick 6.4.1 05/16/08 Q16 
So, on the windows server the $controlPoints array must have all the elements as **INT** values. On the linux server and that image magick version there was no problem if some values were **string** so the solution to the problem was to convert the **$controlPoints** array values into **int** values.

Hope it helps if someone get's over this problem like I did.